# How to get SharePoint "Approval status" column data inside the SharePoint designer 2013 using SharePoint Plus api

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am trying to get share point "ApprovslStatus" column data but don't get answer.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $SP().list("Veradis").get({json:true})
       .then(function(data) {
       console.log(data[0]["ApprovalStatus"]);
     }
   </script>
```

Comment: Be sure to run your JS code in Chrome Developer Tools (or equivalent).  It would highlight your syntax error in red ;)  Look [here](https://www.spguides.com/debugging-javascript-in-chrome-sharepoint/), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/debug-in-vscode) or [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

```
data[0]["_ModerationStatus"]
```

[Moderation Status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sharepoint_protocols/ms-wssfo3/4342322d-6fab-4dc5-8ccd-b808a5e25acf) is a 4-byte integer indicating the moderation approval status of a list item.

Test result:
[image]